# Munkres definition of ordered pair in terms of set operations

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For sets $A$ and $B$, Munkres defines the Cartesian product in the form
$$A \times B = \{(a,b) \mid a \in A, b \in B\}.$$ 
Then, he defines ordered pairs as
$$(a,b) = \{\{a\}, \{a,b\} \}.$$
I was hoping someone could provide some intuition to this definition. I always thought of an ordered pair as some element of the Cartesian plane, not as a set of sets. Is this is simply a definitional thing, this would be fine. But I take it there is some mapping back to intuition that I'm missing.

Comment: an ordered pair has two elements, but the order matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were several attempts to codify ordered pairs in pure set-theoretic terms.  This is Kurawtowski's definition from 1921.  If $P = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$, then $a$ is the unique $x$ satisfying $$\forall A \in P, x \in A$$  Furthermore, $b$ is the unique $y$ satisfying $$(\exists A \in P, y \in A) \wedge (\forall A_1,A_2 \in P, y \in A_1\cap A_2 \implies A_1 = A_2)$$ For more, you can read [Defining the ordered pair using set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Defining_the_ordered_pair_using_set_theory) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

You would like to define the ordered pair $(a,b)$ to be $\{\{a\}, \{b\}\}$ but now you can not distinguish between $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$. So Munkres pairs the $a$ and $b$ together to indicate that $b$ is the second element in the ordered pair.

The reason why we need to do this in the first place is that we would like to be able to say everything in terms of sets. Apriori, $(a,b)$ doesn't have any set-theoretic meaning. That is the purpose of this definition